# R2DBC cannot create statement for notifications

Tags: postgresql, notifications, reactive-programming, r2dbc

I am trying to receive asynchronous notifications from postgresql and r2dbc
I use reactivestream and postgres driver but i cannot make statement
I am new to java and reactivestream, i don't to use a framework like spring.

thank you guys

```
   package com.poc.r2dbc_listen;
import io.r2dbc.postgresql.*;
import io.r2dbc.spi.*;
import org.reactivestreams.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;


public class R2dbc_listen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         PostgresqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
    .host("127.0.0.1")
    .port(5442)  
    .username("postgres")
    .password("psswd")
    .database("database") 
    .build());
    Publisher<? extends Connection> connectionPublisher = connectionFactory.create();
    Flux<Notification> listen = connectionPublisher.createStatement("LISTEN mymessage")
                                .execute()
                                .flatMap(PostgresqlResult::getRowsUpdated)
        .thenMany(receiver.getNotifications());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```java
private void listen() {
    connection = Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
        .cast(PostgresqlConnection.class)
        .block(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    connection.createStatement("LISTEN channel")
        .execute()
        .flatMap(PostgresqlResult::getRowsUpdated)
        .subscribe();

    connection.getNotifications()
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer i will try it monday, and i will give you my feedback.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).